# Check duplicated value in array java, android studio

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I would like to check duplication in the finalChallenges ArrayList. Actually,I'm using while cicle for fill up the finalChallenges Arraylist. If cycle the finalChallenges arrayList contains duplication, then remove it and go forward.

```
 Random random = new Random();
 while (finalChallenges.size()<21) {
       int index = random.nextInt(listChallenges.size());
       finalChallenges.add(listChallenges.get(index));
       if(compare(finalChallenges)){
           inalChallenges.remove(index);
       }
 }
```

compare method:

```
public boolean compare(ArrayList<Challenges> compArray) {
        for (int j=0;j<compArray.size();j++) {
            for (int k = j + 1; k < compArray.size(); k++) {
                if (k != j && compArray.get(k) == compArray.get(j))
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: If you're wanting to get random values out, why not just `Collections#shuffle`? You'll just have to iterate once and then you can ensure you're at least not getting two of the same random element. Outside of that, you might want to look into another collection.

Comment: If you do not want duplicates, why use a List and not a Set?

Comment: @ Rogue  The listChallenges Arraylist has much more elements like finalchallenges, where I can put only 21.So i think that  the Collections#shuffle doesn't work here.

Comment: @Francesc Sorry, but I don't understand the question. Where I shoud use the set?

Comment: Please post a [MCVE]. Since you are not asking about anything Android-specific here, I suggest that you create a small plain ol' Java program that illustrates what you are trying to do. It should be complete enough that we can compile and run it ourselves and see exactly the same output you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Random random = new Random();
                            ArrayList<Challenges> temp = new ArrayList<Challenges>(listChallenges.size());
                            for (Challenges item : listChallenges) temp.add(item);
                            while (finalChallenges.size()<21 && temp.size()>0) {
                                   int index = random.nextInt(temp.size());
                                   finalChallenges.add(temp.get(index));
                                   temp.remove(index);
                            }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Random random = new Random();
final Set<Challenges> challenges = new HashSet<>();
while (challenges.size() < 21) {
    challenges.add(listChallenges.get(random.nextInt(listChallenges.size()));
}

finalChallenges = new ArrayList<>(challenges);
```

Better solution:

```
List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<>(listChallenges.size());
List<Challenges> finalChallenges = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < listChallenges.size(); indices.add(i++));
for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(21, listChallenges.size()); ++i) {
    int index = indices.remove(random.nextInt(indices.size());
    finalChallenges.add(listChallenges.get(index));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, now I understand, but after this the application is freezing.

Comment: This code is fragile, if your list has less than 21 entries it will never exit the loop. Also, if the number of entries is close to 21 it may take a long time to exit the loop. You would be better off with a different approach.

Comment: Yes, this code is really fragile. On the other hand, I solve the problem. Thank you for your help.